# linq select where between dates

Tags: c#, linq, datetime

I'm trying to add to the dates all the events between `Date` and `DateFinal` in order to fill the calendar with the events.

I've already searched but I can't find any solution for this.

```
pageItems.Add("dates", allEvents.Select(i => i.Date).ToList());
```

This is what I have so far but only show the days of `i.Date` and I want to show all of the days between `Date` and `DateFinal`.

Cheers and thanks in advance

In the allEvents I have

```
allEvents = Current.Descendants(n => n.NodeTypeAlias == "EventPage")
            .get_Items()
            .Select(n => new{
            Node = n,
            Date = (Helper.ParseXmlDate(n.GetProperty("itemDate")) ?? n.UpdateDate).DatePart(),
            DateFinal = (Helper.ParseXmlDate(n.GetProperty("itemDateFinal")) ?? n.UpdateDate).DatePart()
                });
```

Comment: Are `Date` and `DateFinal` variables or properties somewhere, or both in the `allEvents` list.

Comment: They are both in the allEvents list.

Comment: Can you clarify your question a bit, Its hard to tell what you are trying to achieve, maybe show what is in `allEvents` and what you need to get out.

Comment: I should have posted before. Sorry!!          allEvents = Current.Descendants(n => n.NodeTypeAlias == "EventPage")
   .get_Items()
   .Select(n => new{Node = n,Date = (Helper.ParseXmlDate(n.GetProperty("itemDate")) ?? n.UpdateDate).DatePart(),      DateFinal = (Helper.ParseXmlDate(n.GetProperty("itemDateFinal")) ?? n.UpdateDate).DatePart()});

Comment: So in the list there is 2 DateTime and you want to select a list of all the Days(DateTime) between those 2 dates?

Comment: Thats right sa_ddam213. Each event as a 'start' date and a 'final' date. I want to add to "dates" all the dates on the interval. Does this make any sense?

Comment: I think so I have added an answer that could be what you need below :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First.. Sorry if I have misunderstood the question

If you have 2 DateTime and you want to select a list of all the Days(as DateTime) between those 2 dates, you could use `Enumerable.Range` using the amount of days between the `Date` and `DateFinal` to loop in your `select` statement to add a day to the start date and output a list of DateTimes

This will select all the dates **between** `Date` and `DateFinal`.

```
  allevents.Select(i => Enumerable.Range(1, (i.DateFinal - i.Date).Days).Select(dayCount => i.Date.AddDays(dayCount))).ToList()
```

If you need to **include** `Date` and `DateFinal` to the list you can use

```
  allevents.Select(i => Enumerable.Range(0, 1 + (i.DateFinal - i.Date).Days).Select(dayCount => i.Date.AddDays(dayCount))).ToList()
```

Input:

```
Date: 02/20/2013
DateFinal: 02/31/2013
```

OutPut:

```
02/20/2013
02/21/2013
02/22/2013
02/23/2013
...
```

Is that what you mean?

Comment: Thanks sa_ddam213. This is what I was looking for. I didn't get the result that I wanted but the problem should be somewhere :[. +1 to you

Comment: I added an edit to include `Date` and `DateFinal` to the list if that's what you need

Answer (score 5):

Use this:

```
allEvents.Where(i => i.Date > Date && i.Date < DateFinal).Select(i => i.Date).ToList()
```

Comment: Thats very good YD1m. I was thinking something like this. However Date and DateFinal are both in the all events list. I reckon that cant access them like this.

Answer (score 2):

You probably searching for:

```
TimeSpan span=d2-d1;
span.TotalDays;
```

so it *should* look like:

```
allEvents.Select(i => (DateFinal - i.Date).TotalDays).ToList()
```

This shows *all days between some DateFinal and i.Date*

If this is not what you're searching for, please clarify.

Comment: I think this is it! I'll have a look and see if I can get this working!